# kivy vs android studios vs hybrid which works best for beginners

Tags: android, kivy

I just finished a course on php and java-script and I want to go into Android app development with pythons kivy but I want to know if it is possible to access native functionality geolocation,camera,vibrator,gallery,flash light and other android native features with kivy and how easily can I do it ..

Answer (score 1):

> i want to know if it is possible to access native functionality

Yes. Accessing a lot of native functionality is possible with **[Plyer](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** - a library for accessing features of your platform's hardware.

Kivy does not have GPS functionality or Notifications, but since Kivy uses Python, you can import any Python library or framework into it.

Here's another **[link](https://github.com/kivy/plyer)** showing what functionalities and supported APIs you can get out of Plyer on each of the various platforms (Android, iOS, Mac, Windows, Linux).

---

> kivy vs android studios vs hybrid which works best for beginners

It depends on the beginner. I would make a list of recommendations based on their background.

**No background:**

- Learn Java (or Kotlin) and use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html).

**Any C-based background or OOP background:**

- Android Studio
- [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/) (C#) in Visual Studio

**Any web or javascript background:**

- [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)
- Android Studio
- [Iconic](https://ionicframework.com/)
- [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/)

**Any scripting background:**

- [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) which can be setup in [various IDEs](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's).
- Android Studio.

At the end of the day, my final recommendation would be to use Android Studio because it's the official IDE for Android app development.

**Note**: I currently use Android Studio, so I'm *slightly* biased towards it.